# Publishing Dynamic CT fails after 2013 upgrade

Tags: 2013-sp1, dynamic-publishing

After 2013 SP1 upgrade, when publishing dynamic components status says **success** but the content is not getting updated on the web page.

Then I tried to publish the **dynamic CT** which is rendered when publishing the dynamic components. Publishing **fails** in this case.

Could you please help me with your inputs if anyone has come across this sort of issue.

Please Note: Publishing pages or normal components are working as expected(able to see latest changes on the web page).

Please find the error details below.

**Error:** Committing Deployment failed 
       Phase: Deployment prepare commit phase failed
       Unable to prepare transaction:

Comment: What is the error when publishing fails?

Comment: @SaurabhGangwar - I have updated my question with the error message.

Comment: To get a good answer, Please update the question with Error Stack Trace.

Answer (score 5):

The error you describe when publishing the CT will be evident in the log stacktrace.  This is probably a "Request Entity Too Large" error, meaning that the number of Component Presentations that end up being rendered and sent to the Deployer based on the CT amounts to a bigger size than you have configured in your cd_deployer_conf.xml (default is 10 megs).

The error, however, is most likely not related to why the changes of the published Components using this CT don't show up when refreshing your webpage.

This is often a cause of object cache on the website being turned on without the Cache Channel Service.  One way to check if your Component is successfully getting into the Broker is looking in the Component_Presentations table in the DB.  First unpublish, check that the table has no record, then republish and see if a record got created.  If it is created, then the problem is not the Deployer or the publishing process - it is the website config.

If it is the website config, then most likely you have the object cache set to "true" in your cd_storage_conf.ml, but the Cache Channel Service not being configured correctly. So you won't be getting updated content when it's republished.  Check that the Cache Channel Service is running (if .NET, then it's a Windows Service on one of the CD machines (and sometimes with JMS); if Java it could be a standalone command line program or JMS configuration), if the service is up, this could be firewall settings for the RMI ports to be open for the Cache Channel Service.

Comment: Thanks Nick, As you mentioned in my case when publishing the Dynamic CT, when I check see items to publish, The list is too large.

Comment: Exactly, when you publish a template it means that Tridion will publish every content item associated with that template.  For e.g. if you publish a dynamic CT that is linked to a Schema "Article" and you have 10,000 Article Components, then Tridion will attempt to publish 10,000 Article Component Presentations - which is a lot.  So in this case, don't publish the CT, publish each Component.

Answer (score 3):

First thing that you should try to figure out whether the issue is related to the publishing process or the code which is fetching the dynamic content from the Broker DB to display on the web pages.

You may try to check in the Broker DB whether the corresponding component have an entry over there (Please mind that you won't be able to see the actual content as it would be in Encoded format there) - If it is there then it should be an error related to the Code written to fetch this data from the Broker DB and display on the Web page - In this case; ensure you have re-compiled your code with the latest Broker API (I am assuming you are using Broker API instead of the OData service) and try again. If you have used the OData Service to fetch the data from the Broker DB and displayed on the Website; I would recommend debugging your code.

**There might be a case that you are publishing to the some other Broker Database but your code is directed to some other Broker Database to fetch the data.**

On the other hand; if your content is not at all available in the Broker DB; we need to figure out why the publishing is not working - It could be an error/configuration issue in the Storage Config or it could be anything else - I would recommend in this case you share more details about any error that might be coming in the Event Viewer/Content Delivery Error Logs.

I hope this helps.